# Use SAS Proc SQL to Find Rows Where All Columns Are Not Missing?

Tags: sql, sas

I would like to use SAS Proc SQL to find me row in a table in which every column has a non-missing value.  Is there a way to do this without having to list all of the column names? This did not work, but it might give you an idea of what my intended output is.

```
Proc SQL;
    Select *
    from work.table
    Where * is not null;
Run;
```

I would also like to limit the results to one observation if possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nontrivial in SQL since you cannot get all variables in one item without using the macro language.  In the datastep, this is trivial.

```
data class;
  set sashelp.class;
  if mod(_n_,3)=1 then call missing(age);
run;

data want;
  set class;
  if cmiss(of _all_)=0;
run;
```

`cmiss` indicates a 1 if a character or numeric variable is missing (and specifically in this case counts the total number of missings).  You can use the `obs=1` option on the data step to limit to one.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you.  For the record for anyone in the future who may want to use Joe's code, just change the  if cmiss(of _all_) equal to 1 instead of 0 to get a row with all non-missing values .

Comment: Why change it to 1?  Then that means you look for a row with *one* missing value.  All nonmissing would be 0.

Comment: You are right. Originally the cmiss = 0 does returned no results, but I now realize it's because there is a column in the original table where every row has a missing value.  When I remove that column, yes the cmiss=0 is correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you have to be explicit.  `*` is not a general purpose macro that expands out the columns.  It is a syntactic elements that happens to be used in `select *` and `count(*)`.

So, something like this:

```
Proc SQL;
    Select *
    from work.table
    Where col1 is not null and col2 is not null and col3 is not null . . .
Run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL and dictionary tables:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select cats('not missing(', name, ')')
    into :expression separated by " and "
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname = "SASHELP" and memname = "CLASS";
quit;

proc sql outobs=1;  
    select *
    from sashelp.class
    where &expression.;
quit;
```